# Haskell semantics undefined value

Tags: haskell, undefined, semantics

I am new to Haskell and to its semantics. I learned that not every function can be mapped to an object. For instance:

```
square :: Int -> Int 
square x = x*x
```

The value of square is mapped to the math object. However, for any non-terminating function, we map it to a special math value `⊥`. I want to know what will happen if I have to do calculation with this undefined value. For instance, I have a set of numbers `Z⊥ ={⊥, 1,0,-1}`. What will be the output if I multiply `⊥` with 1? Since, the type of `⊥` will be undefined, am I able to do multiplication with a well defined type? Since, `⊥` is in the domain of `Z⊥`, I guess I can do the multiplication. But, then it will have to return `⊥`! I would like to have some guidance regarding it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication will also return `⊥`. It behaves exactly like you described; any computation that depends on the `⊥` value will also yield `⊥`.

```
2 * undefined ~= undefined
```

The bottom value is an inhabitant of every type, and is thus an implicit member of every value set and cannot be excluded by types (Except by using GHC internal primitives). The reason for the existence of this special value is to make it possible to argue about the Halting Problem in Haskell; without this value, the compiler would have to be able to prove that a certain computation terminates in order for it to type-check, and this is generally not possible.

Comment: As a further note, `f ⊥ ≠ ⊥` is permitted if and only if for all x, `f x = f ⊥`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "any computation that depends on the `⊥` value," which is the above expressed in layman's terms: if `f` does not depend on `x`, the function may yield a concrete value when applied to the bottom value. On a different note, `⊥ ≠ ⊥`, which is why I invented the ambiguous "equivalence" operator above ;)

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Not true; consider `f x = (x, x)`. The correct rule is `f ⊥ ⊑ f x` for all `x`.

Comment: The nice thing about Haskell functions is that they are monotone with regards to _lifted discrete CPO_ (with the relation being ⊑ - less defined than), i.e. x ⊑ y ⇒ f x ⊑ f y. On language side, this is guaranteed by the inability to pattern match on ⊥.

Comment: What makes you say ⊥ ≠ ⊥?  To me, ⊥ is just a element in our denotational semantics for describing pure Haskell programs, and since our denotational semantics are defined in terms of ordinary logic, it necessarily follows that ⊥ = ⊥.